# Sending Image to server stopped after 1 min to 1.5 min

Tags: java

i am trying to send image which have been captured from webcam to server...
client sent pictures to server successfully but after some time like 1 min
or 50 sec or sometimes 1.5 mins image stopped.... can some one help??

Client side:-
            BufferedImage temp= (BufferedImage)image.getBufferedImage();
            try {
                s.getOutputStream().flush();

```
            ImageIO.write(temp, "png", s.getOutputStream());


            s.getOutputStream().flush();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
```

Server Side:-

while(true)
{

```
    img = ImageIO.read(sc.getInputStream());
    if(img!=null)
    {
    IplImage tempray = IplImage.createFrom(img);


    fram.showImage(tempray);
    }
```

}

it work perfectly fine for some time but after that it stopped displaying
means image stopped........

Comment: Please post complete testable code.

Comment: how are you exiting from the while loop on the server side?

Comment: yeah their is a while loop exist in server side